# Архитектура БД: Использование множества полей\таблиц или хранение информации в одном поле через JSON

Tags: sql, база-данных, json, архитектура

Допустим у нас есть сущность `User`

> Какие данные могут быть:
>
> 1. Id
> 2. Username
> 3. Password
> 4. Email
> 5. Status
> 6. Phone
>
>    - phone1
>    - phone2
>    - ...
>    - phoneX
> 7. Lastname
> 8. Firstname
> 9. Avatar
> 10. Aboutme

---

### Способ 1

С точки зрения обычного структурирования по идее структура должна быть такая:

**User** // храним основную "функциональную" информацию о пользователе

- Id / Username / Password / Email / Status

**User_info** // храним дополнительную "контентную" информацию о пользователе

- Id / info_id / user_id / value

**Info_items** // храним какую информацию может иметь пользователь

- id / code / name

**Связи простые:**

- Info_items.id <=> User_info.info_id
- User.id <=> User_info.user_id

---

### Способ 2

Мы будем хранить все данные в одной единственной таблице `User`, однако контентные данные будут кодироваться в JSON и добавляться в одно поле Info:

**User**

- Id / Username / Password / Email / Status / Info

---

### Вопросы

Так как оба способа являются универсальными (то есть если завтра добавится еще 5-10-100 полей для контентной информации о пользователе, нам не придется менять практически ничего), поэтому больше интересуют вопросы оптимизации

**1. Какой способ предпочтительнее с точки зрения оптимизации и скорости запросов?**

- Чтобы получить полную информацию в первом способе мне нужно будет
  создавать SQL запросы с использование JOIN
- Чтобы получить полную информацию во втором способе мне достаточно использовать элементарный SQL запрос, и потом на серверном языке декодировать поле `Info`   (json_decode)
- Если у нас будет задача искать пользователей по контентной информации (например номер телефона) какие запросы будут выполняться быстрее: **для 2ого способа** `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE info like "phone%123456%"` (или поиск по более точному регулярному выражению) или **для 1ого способа**`SELECT * FROM USER as u JOIN user_info as ui ON u.id = ui.user_id JOIN info_items as ii ON ui.info_id = ii.id AND ii.code = 'phone' WHERE ui.value = '123456'`

**2. хз, советы на эту тему? :)**

**p.s.** изучать базы данных, нормализации и прочее я планирую, но пока, к сожалению, не хватает на это времени

Comment: вы не сможете сделать `info like 'phone%....%'`, вам придется делать `info like '%phone...`, что вообще не поддается оптимизации и требует полного сканирования таблицы. кроме того ваш lile найдет не только телефоны с этим номером, но и любые другие данные, лежащие после слова phone. В общем, если предполагается хоть какая то обработка информации в БД (включая поиск) и БД не располагает собственными средствами работы с json (включая json-индексы) хранить json не стоит. Но json может например дублировать реляционно лежащие данные, для быстрого доступа

Comment: И да, при нормализованном хранении при текущем наборе атрибутов, вам понадобится 2 таблицы Users и Phones, т.е. только телефоны надо выносить в отдельную таблицу, все остальное можно спокойно хранить в записи пользователя отдельными полями

Comment: @Mike по поводу `info like 'phone%....%'` согласен, ошибся, но там есть приписка про поиск по регулярному выражению.

Comment: И представьте себе ситуацию, что вы хотите найти людей с одинаковыми телефонами. (например что бы проверить не создает ли один человек много аккаунтов). Если данные в json вам скорее всего придется вытянуть все данные на клиента и там долго парсить и искать ... Запрос делающий это на стороне БД будет настолько жутким, что думать даже не хочется. Так что все сводится к тому, что же вы хотите потом делать с этими данными ...

Comment: @Mike по поводу 2ого комментария - в первом способе я сделал такую структуру из расчета, что в будущем могут появиться еще поля

Comment: Да, если "поля в будущем", то типичный EAV, как вы и сделали. И да, EAV очень тормозной, когда надо получить всю информацию по конкретно сущности. В целях оптимизации по скорости часто вносят дублирование информации, т.е. хранят для целей поиска и формализации в EAV, и дополнительную сводную копию в основной таблице в json (или чем то подобном)